# Unable to knit to PDF in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to knit to PDF in R and get the following code. Any ideas about how to resolve? Thank you!

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
Quitting from lines 11-36 (aswimmer_EconPS1.Rmd) 
Error in View(aid_workers) : X11 dataentry cannot be loaded
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> View

Execution halted
```

Comment: There's very little here to go on. I would first check to see if you properly define the objects "aid_workers" and maybe "X11" inside the .Rmd document.

Comment: Are you sure you want to `View()` a dataset in your PDF? `View()` is used to open up the data set in a separate window, not sure what the purpose is of trying to use it to make a PDF. If you want to insert a table into your PDF, use `knitr::kable` (or choices from the many other packages that make tables).

Comment: Install XCode/ update Xcode on your Mac, and reinstall packages `rlang` and `dplyr` to help fix your xcrun error, even update R as well if you can